# Is there any way to store a value in a separate entity?

Tags: javascript, android, sql, io, counter

I'm trying to show a non-specific counter in my website (hosted on AWS, which takes the code from the github page containing all the files), one that possibly, I'd be able to edit (increment/decrement) through another piece of software made by myself (possibly an app, as I'd need it to be portable).

I've read about localStorage but it wouldn't work because I'm trying to access the value from two different devices and obtain it the same.

I have some extremely rudimentary understanding of SQL, if that could be used in this situation.

How could I do this?

I'm not really good at explaining what I mean, so I drew a rough sketch of what I mean:
[image]

Comment: A database seems like a reasonable strategy. Depending on your context, a flat file might also work.

Comment: so, you'll need a server ...

Comment: You might find these helpful: [Create and Connect to a MySQL Database with Amazon RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/create-mysql-db/) and [AWS RDS MySQL Database Setup (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ng_zi11N4_c) and [Create a MySQL database on AWS (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3jH1YxJqaY).